# Moving the text up?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I have this [page](http://posnation.com/our_customers/) and if you look at the top right search...i need to move the text search just about 2px to make it center with the image but i text-align vertical-align or padding are not doing what i want here is my css

```
#Search {
background: url("/images/no-letters-search.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
border: medium none;
font-size: 15px;
height: 37px;
left: 31px;
padding-left: 26px;
position: relative;
top: -3px;
width: 175px;
font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

and here is my html

```
<form id="search_form" method="post" action="/mm5/merchant.mvc?">
 <input type="text" name="Search" id="Search" tabindex="0" />
 <input name="Screen" type="hidden" value="SRCH" />
</form>
```

Comment: firefox 4 on the mac is my browser but i am looking at all of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Erm, try `line-height:18px;` - that might do it.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above try setting line-height, to the height of the input box that should center a single line text.

Answer (score 0):

The text is actually already centered with the input field. The problem is your input field is taller than the actual image you've placed behind it, so visually, it looks off (technically, it's already centered).

Your current input field is 37 pixels high, but because the input field is a box model element with a border on it (medium), your box is actually around 41 pixels tall. You need to either remove the border or just cut down the size of the input field to something like 34px or 33px.

Or you could just properly rewrite "border: medium none;" to "border: 0".

If none of that makes sense, I suggest studying the CSS box model a bit at http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html.